# How to disable Eclipse's "auto-folding during typing"?

Tags: eclipse, folding, eclipse-jdt

Eclipse (any version AFAIK) has some weird behavior related to folding in Java code. Suppose I’m editing this class:

```java
class A {
  String field;
  @Nonnull 
  Object method(){
    // whatever
  }
}
```

If folding is enabled and I tell it to collapse everything (it’s Control-NumSlash in mine, but that might be customized), the method is correctly folded, i.e. it shows only `Object method()...` for the method. All good ’till now.

The part that bothers me is that if I move the cursor right after `field;`, press Enter, and type something like “`public`”, and then stop for a second, Eclipse automatically folds that word into the method below.

That might seem reasonable (presumably it assumes I wanted to add that qualifier to the method); but in practice what I’m actually doing is trying to add a new method, and paused for a moment to think about its return type or maybe its name. (If I wanted to modify the method I’d unfold it first, since it might already have that qualifier, folded.)

I hate this “feature” with passion, but I can’t for the life of me find out how to disable it, nor even which of the damned mess of plugins (that Eclipse keeps insisting I should not be allowed to remove) is responsible for it so I can file a bug report.

So, does anyone know (1) where does that behavior come from, and hopefully (2) how can I get rid of it but keep manual folding? Thanks!

(For the record, I’m using Kepler SR1, but this behavior goes back a really long time, at least five years or so.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to prevent it from doing that unless you just make a habit of putting a semicolon `;` or closing curly brace `}` after `public` which prevents the `Object method(){..` from 'folding' it up. I believe it's written to fold everything up until the closest semicolon which is why `@Nonnull` is also included.

The only options for folding I can find are located in **Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > folding**

I would consider this to be a bug, or just a feature that had unintended side effects.

*Funny enough, if you put almost any symbol or misspell `public` it wont fold it.*

Comment: Good point about typing a symbol, thank you. Parentheses work as well. I might try that until I have the time to figure out how to submit a patch.

Comment: This behaviour still distracts a lot when writing. Even 7 years later I only find this answer addressing the problem, and the solution to write code in a way the IDE likes it is bad DX. Is there no better solution?

Comment: @Mathias If it's been bothering you for 7 years, why haven't you proposed a patch yet? Probably most (including me) have never faced this issue, because they do not use _Collapse All_ or use the content assist to create a method (e.g. typing `pub` and then, without taking a nap, hitting Ctrl+Space; the open content assist prevents to get something hidden). And even if it happened to me, I would just hit Ctrl+Q (or Ctrl+Alt+Left) to go back to the last edit location.